# Why can't I login to Grafana with Keycloak integration?

Tags: keycloak, grafana

I'm facing issue with Keycloak integration in Grafana:

With this `grafana.ini`:

```
instance_name = grafana

[log]
level = error

[server]
; domain = host.docker.internal
root_url = http://localhost:13000
enforce_domain = false
enable_gzip = true

[security]
admin_user = admin
admin_password = admin

[auth.generic_oauth]
name = OAuth
enabled = true
client_id = grafana
; client_secret = CLIENT_SECRET_FROM_KEYCLOAK
client_secret = <my client secret>
scopes = openid profile roles
; email_attribute_name = email:primary
auth_url = http://<keycloak IP>/auth/realms/mcs/protocol/openid-connect/auth
token_url = http://<keycloak IP>/auth/realms/mcs/protocol/openid-connect/token
api_url = http://<keycloak IP>/auth/realms/mcs/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
allow_sign_up = false
disable_login_form = true
oauth_auto_login = true
tls_skip_verify_insecure = true

; Roles from Client roles in Keycloak
role_attribute_path = contains(resource_access.grafana.roles[*], 'Admin') && 'Admin' || contains(resource_access.grafana.roles[*], 'Editor') && 'Editor' || 'Viewer'
```

I can be redirected to Keycloak login page, but after login grafana has this error:

```
t=2021-10-15T11:48:58+0000 lvl=eror msg=login.OAuthLogin(NewTransportWithCode) logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= error="oauth2: cannot fetch token: 400 Bad Request\nResponse: {\"error\":\"invalid_grant\",\"error_description\":\"Code not valid\"}"
t=2021-10-15T11:48:58+0000 lvl=eror msg="Request Completed" logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= method=GET path=/login/generic_oauth status=500 remote_addr=172.18.0.1 time_ms=647 size=733 referer=
```

Keycloak configuration for grafana client:
[image]
[image]
[image]

What happens? What I am missing from configuration?

---

**EDIT:**

Grafana URL: `http://localhost:13000`

Keycloak logs:

```
16:38:09,650 ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (default task-4) Uncaught server error: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot map type for token claim
...
...

16:38:09,942 WARN  [org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.utils.OAuth2CodeParser] (default task-4) Code 'f72beb89-f814-4993-aa8f-e8debfea41ae' already used for userSession '6de1f56b-9c61-42ae-86bd-66d0ac7ad751' and client '36930d87-854f-414a-8177-c8237edf805c'.
16:38:09,944 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-4) type=CODE_TO_TOKEN_ERROR, realmId=mcs, clientId=grafana, userId=null, ipAddress=172.16.1.1, error=invalid_code, grant_type=authorization_code, code_id=6de1f56b-9c61-42ae-86bd-66d0ac7ad751, client_auth_method=client-secret
```

Comment: Pls provide Grafana URL used for authentication + Keycloak logs.

Comment: provided grafana URL and Keycloak logs.

Comment: There is many problems, but there is nothing obvious about root cause. Issue: https should be used on Keycloak/Grafana side (that's mandatory for OIDC), it doesn't make sense to have client roles (user roles are usually better fit), `Claim JSON Type` in the mapper definition is wrong (why you don't use default `roles` scope), ... Recommendation: remove mapper and start with authentication only first. Confire authorization later, when authentication is working. Start login procedure from the scratch always (don't refresh error page).

Comment: now I have the errors: `t=2021-10-15T20:03:11+0000 lvl=eror msg="invalid username or password" logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname=
t=2021-10-15T20:03:11+0000 lvl=eror msg="Failed to look up user based on cookie" logger=context error="user token not found"` and nothing in Keycloak logs